# Populate angular table using google sheets

Tags: angular, google-sheets

I would like to populate a table using angular 6 with data coming from google sheets. I'm using this npm package [get-sheet-done](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-sheet-done) to generate a JSONP and that way get the data in the google sheets as a json which I can access and turn into a subscription so that data in my table changes when people modify the data in the sheet.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as GetSheetDone from 'get-sheet-done';

export interface Table {
  id: number,
  nombre: string, 
  apellido: string, 
  email: string,
  telefono: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  docKey: String = "<google sheets document key>";
  sheetNum: number = 1;
  characters: Table[];

constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPeople()
    .subscribe((data: Table[])=>{
      this.characters = data;
    });

  }
  getPeople(){
    return GetSheetDone.labeledCols(this.docKey, this.sheetNum).then(sheet=>{
      console.log(sheet);
      sheet.data      
    });
  }       
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Telefono</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let character of characters">
      <td>{{ character.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ character.nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ character.apellido }}</td>
      <td>{{ character.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ character.telefono }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button (click)="getPeople()">Get Data</button>
```

the error that i'm getting is

> this.getPeople(...).subscribe is not a function

here is the  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-863rpx)

If you guys got any other suggestion of packages to do what i'm trying they are welcome

Comment: I'm not sure if this works the same way as I do it, but you could simply publish your sheet and get the JSON from that. Here are the notes I wrote up on how to figure that out. https://ng-chicago.github.io/2018/05/24/google-sheets-as-a-json-data-source/

Comment: Is it your expectation that changes in the spreadsheet will always automatically show in your Angular app? I think like most other calls to a service, you will get the data only once when the app is loaded or refreshed. You could possibly use something like setInterval to get new data every XX minutes.

Comment: I checked your resorces and currently working on implementing them to see if it works. Yes i would like that changes on the sheet reflect on the app, and it's pretty clever the use of setInterval, will keep in mind

Comment: I have Angular example loads data from that google sheet here. Nothing pretty. Probably over engineered. If you like to poke around the source code for that, let me know and I will update GitHub. You can use any part that may be helpful. https://mypets.glitch.me/#/

Comment: omg! YES please! would love to see the codes

Answer (score 4):

4 easy steps to figure out how to get JSON data from a Spreadsheet tab.
No special packages needed.
https://ng-chicago.github.io/2018/05/24/google-sheets-as-a-json-data-source/

An Angular PWA example using the spreadsheet mentioned above

--- Running Deployed (ugly) App
--- https://mypets.glitch.me/#/

--- Source Code
--- https://github.com/ng-chicago/MyPets

Notes:
-- This is a PWA, so if you add to home screen (A2HS) when prompted and use that icon, it will open in a standalone window
-- All of the data is loaded when the app is initialized. No need to press the button until you want fresh data.
-- Since a service is being used to get the data, clicking on a refresh button may seem like nothing happened if the data in the spreadsheet did not change. If you watch the dev tools network tab, you will see the data being retrieved.
-- Be careful with the .htaccess file. If you are not sure what that is for, delete it. Do not deploy to your server.
-- Steal any part that may be helpful.
-- If you have questions, feel free to ping me on Twitter @AngularChicago

Answer (score 0):

In order to load data from a Google Sheets document into your Angular app you may also use [ng-google-sheets-db](https://github.com/FranzDiebold/ng-google-sheets-db-library). I also made a [demo application](https://franzdiebold.github.io/ng-google-sheets-db-library/) and a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-google-sheets-db-demo) to show the usage of the lib.

You may install it using

```sh
ng add ng-google-sheets-db
```

or

```sh
npm install ng-google-sheets-db
```

Then you need to add `GoogleSheetsDbService` to your app's module as a provider and Angular's `HttpClientModule` to the imports.

The full documentation is available at https://github.com/FranzDiebold/ng-google-sheets-db-library#usage.